# Only update when where clause is same as $_SESSION

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, where-clause

I am having trouble updating my profil page. I can update it but then it will updat all the records so I thought I only update when the Username (Gebruikersnaam) is the same as the session username ($_SESSION['USER']).

This is what I have tried but this isn't working for me.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["wijzig"])) {
   global $db;
   $Voorletters = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Voorletters"]);
   $Tussenvoegsel = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Tussenvoegsel"]);
   $Achternaam = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Achternaam"]);
   $Adres = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Adres"]);
   $Postcode = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Postcode"]);
   $Woonplaats = htmlspecialchars($_POST["Woonplaats"]);
   $Gebruikersnaam = $_SESSION['USER'];
    $sql1 = "UPDATE klant SET Voorletters=:voorletters, Tussenvoegsel=:tussenvoegsel, Achternaam=:achternaam, Adres=:adres, Postcode=:postcode, Woonplaats=:woonplaats
    WHERE Gebruikersnaam = $Gebruikersnaam";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql1);
    $data = array("voorletters" => $Voorletters, "tussenvoegsel" => $Tussenvoegsel, "achternaam" => $Achternaam, "adres" => $Adres, "postcode" => $Postcode, "woonplaats" => $Woonplaats);

    try {
        $stmt->execute($data);

    } 
    catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }
} 
?>
```

The error I get:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'faas' in
>   'where clause'

This is my first question so let me know if I missed some information or someting. Hope you guys can help me out!

Comment: You need to parameterize all the data!

Answer (score 1):

```
"UPDATE klant SET Voorletters=:voorletters, Tussenvoegsel=:tussenvoegsel, Achternaam=:achternaam, Adres=:adres, Postcode=:postcode, Woonplaats=:woonplaats
    WHERE Gebruikersnaam = '$Gebruikersnaam'";
```

You are missing the quotes in the `WHERE` clause. You should use a prepared statement for that though, cause your code is open to SQL injection.